# SSIS Outputbuffer error "primeoutput method on script component returned success, but did not report an end of rowset"

Tags: c#, ssis

I am running an SSIS script task to get data from an api to sql server. I have created output buffer and mapped all the columns. This script was running fine until recently I added more script tasks to the flow that have similar setup. Now when I run the package it gives me the below error and fails.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: The Primeoutput method on "Script Component" returned success, but did not report an end of the rowset. There is an error in the component. It should have reported and end-of-row. The Pipeline will shut down execution to avoid unpreditable results.

When I just run the task individually then it runs fine. only when I run the entire flow this error shows up.

Can some one please help on how to fix this.

Thank you

Comment: So if you post some code we might have a better clue......?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the exact error message.

Answer (score 3):

For the next person that comes along and finds this is the ONLY Google result for the error message:

> The Primeoutput method on "Script Component" returned success, but did not report an end of the rowset. There is an error in the component. It should have reported and end-of-row. The Pipeline will shut down execution to avoid unpredictable results.

I don't know the reason, but the root cause is copy/pasting your script task so you don't have to duplicate effort. Something about the script breaks SSIS when it is copy / pasted. I created a new script task instead and just copy/pasted the code itself into it and it worked fine.